Problemas con Angular
Los pongo en contexto, me pidieron crear una app en angular, con un servidor con Node.js y express. Compila todo y funciona de maravilla, pero este será un servicio local, quiere decir que solo en la red local.
Cuando utilizo
baseUrl : 'http://localhost:3009/api'

funciona perfecto, pero cuando cambio el localhost por la IP ya no funciona y me da este error
historia.service.ts:32 ERROR 
HttpErrorResponse {headers: _HttpHeaders, status: 0, statusText: 'Unknown Error', url: 'http://192.168.22.90:3009/api/mostrarHistoria', ok: false, …}
error
: 
ProgressEvent {isTrusted: true, lengthComputable: false, loaded: 0, total: 0, type: 'error', …}
headers
: 
_HttpHeaders {normalizedNames: Map(0), lazyUpdate: null, headers: Map(0)}
message
: 
"Http failure response for http://192.168.x.x:3009/api/mostrarHistoria: 0 Unknown Error"
name
: 
"HttpErrorResponse"
ok
: 
false
status
: 
0
statusText
: 
"Unknown Error"
url
: 
"http://192.168.x.x:3009/api/mostrarHistoria"
[[Prototype]]
: 
HttpResponseBase


historia.service.ts:32 
        
        
       GET https://192.168.x.x:3009/api/mostrarHistoria net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR

Disculpen por las malas prácticas y si me ayudarían con mejores prácticas se los agradecería mucho.
(Actualización)
Tengo mi archivo enviroment que le envía la variable BaseUrl y es donde agrego la dirección de la siguiente manera,
export const environment = { baseUrl : 'http://192.168.x.x:3009/api', }
Por lo que mi service queda de esta manera
typescript
Copy code
export class HistoriaService {
private baseUrl: string ;
constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) {     
    this.baseUrl  = environment.baseUrl;   
}     

obtenerMainPage() {     
    return firstValueFrom(
        this.httpClient.get<any>(`${this.baseUrl}/mostrarPaginaPrincipal`)
    );   
}  

}
¿Alguna idea de por qué podría estar ocurriendo esto?

Primero, el "unknown error" está como para tirarse los pelos, pero veo que usas https y al final dice ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR. ¿Has intentado invocarlo con http (sin s)? Pregunto porque puede ser tema de mala configuración de la conexión segura.

Si, tengo un archivo enviroment para enviar la baseUrl  que es http pero no entiendo porque motivo lo envia como https mi servicio quedaria de la siguiente manera.
`export class HistoriaService {
private baseUrl: string ;
constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) {
this.baseUrl  = environment.baseUrl;
}
obtenerMainPage() {
return firstValueFrom(
this.httpClient.get(${this.baseUrl}/mostrarPaginaPrincipal)
);
}
}código`

No agregues ese código en comentarios, dale clic a [edit] y agrégalo a la pregunta.

Listo muchas gracias

Asegúrate de que en el html no tienes un  tag que tenga el contenido Content-Security-Policy con el valor upgrade-insecure-requests.

Perfecto, ya funciona, era justo eso. Como puedo poner tu comentario como respuesta, Muchísimas gracias de corazón <3
